# PHP hashing method, same output every time

Tags: php, hash

So if I do something like `sha1($data)` the result will be `BLAHBLAH123`. However if I do it again it will be `BLAHAHS316`. The same thing happens with `md5`. So my question is, what is a consistent way to hash values?

So like `function($data)` will return `BLAHBLAHBLAH123` each time it is evaluated with the same `$data` parameter.

EDIT: I have a specific purpose in mind for this that isn't passwords so security isn't a concern.

EDIT: For example, `md5($data)` will not return `BLAHBLAH` every time, sometimes it'll return `BLAHHHAL`. I don't want that. I want it to return the same thing, `BLAHBLAH` everytime!

Answer (score 3):

The output of a hashing operation will only change if the input has changed.

For example:

```
echo sha1( 'test' );

a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3
```

If you wish it to change everytime, you *could* append a timestamp to the input:

```
echo sha1( 'test'.time() )

3d68b7693768f199623f31f820b1ba29b0a58769
```

Comment: I tried doing sha1 and it changed every other time.
And I want it to stay the same and NOT change.

Comment: Can you confirm that `$data` is not changing somehow?

Comment: Let me try this again, I might of been wrong. And yes I can.

Comment: Okay, you were right. I guess I did something wrong the first time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hashing function are [deterministic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_algorithm) (they would be useless if this was not the case).

> In computer science, a deterministic algorithm is *an algorithm which, given a particular input, will always produce the same output*, with the underlying machine always passing through the same sequence of states.

Consider another (eg. time) input to the domain as in `sha1(microtime() . $data)` if you want 'different output'. I'm not sure how useful this will be in practice.

Password hash functions use a [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) (randomly generated, stored separately) as additional input so the same plain-text password will result in a different stored hash value.

Answer (score 0):

Hashing method - to give the same value, but not easy to predict or decode is what i think you are looking for.

You can use use a constant string val and do a hash of that string to get the same value always, if you want to change the value you can change the constant and get a different hash value

```
$constStr = "hashThis";
$hashWord = md5($constStr);

// it will return the same value always, as long as the constStr is the  same
```

Answer (score 0):

Two different input with same `md5` or `sha1` output?

That's possible but way to hard. Take a look at here: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1434/are-there-two-known-strings-which-have-the-same-md5-hash-value

Answer (score 0):

The return value will change as long as your $data variable changes, you can't get same hashing value from different strings